# Should the [issues] tag be removed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

Just noticed a new question posted with the tag [issues](/questions/tagged/issues)

Seems like that tag is completely meaningless and should be removed to me.

Comment: Someone needs to create a community wiki question where we can make a list of useless tags and their status until they're blacklisted. Nominating not me.

Comment: @agf - Are you volunteering to be that Someone? (Edit: Just saw your edit. Too quick for me!). Agreed though.

Comment: Just make this a community wiki (can you do that?) and make the title something like "Stack Overflow Tag Blacklist Suggestions"

Comment: @agf - Yes. I suppose only problem there is that some of the tags might warrant greater discussion.

Comment: There are a lot of pretty useless ones -- `share`, `reccomendation`, `features`, `options`, `improvement` -- and at least then the mods or people who wanted to do retagging would only have to look in one place.

Comment: I can't make this CW myself (only a mod can do that to questions)

Comment: I've gone through the questions with this tag and retagged any potential orphans. Occasionally, this tag is used to mean issue tracking or known issues, both of which already have tags; I retagged these instances. Having a tag which generically indicates a problem is worthless, since posting a question should make it obvious that one has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The tag is used to mean "I have an issue" in questions that have very little in common, such as:

- [Two Xcode app icons in launchpad after 4.5 install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519772/two-xcode-app-icons-in-launchpad-after-4-5-install)
- [Exhaustive search finds nothing: Android emulator loads only emergency call app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451469/exhaustive-search-finds-nothing-android-emulator-loads-only-emergency-call-app)
- [cakephp 2.2.2 database connection with mssql sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404133/cakephp-2-2-2-database-connection-with-mssql-sql-server)
- [MVC3 CkEditor performance rendering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306447/mvc3-ckeditor-performance-rendering-issue)

There are 330 questions using [issues](/questions/tagged/issues). (Previously, they were 314.) The tag should be burninated.