# We seem to have some issues here...​

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Specifically, we seem to have 365 questions tagged with [issues](/questions/tagged/issues).

Please burninate.

Comment: ... what next? a [question] tag for questions that are questions?

Comment: I like the wiki: _"Questions related with any issues you have using software products.  If you encounter strange errors, the software, operating system, integrated development environment or tool is no longer working as expected, you may add this tag."_

Comment: Misleading title. This is just one issue.

Comment: @BoltClock: No, we don't have an "issue". [I checked.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/issue)

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: Dammit, foiled.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Should we also add "Please refrain to post the question on SuperUser or any other fitting site and post it here"? Or it would be funnier to ask Jeff about the "0 question**s** tagged" label so to have the possibility to meet the legend first person (disclaimer: joke - do NOT do it)?

Comment: one issue for every day in the year?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist In English, every number that is not 1 is plural. `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, but if you ask Jeff, even 1 (or -1) is plural. Anyway, I wouldn't do it - last time he promised to hit anyone who did it with a giand "S"... So while it may be fun to meet him, you would need a trip to the hospital soon after...

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Actually, he promised that for the next person opening a bug report about plurals. Since then, a lot of water passed under the bridge. Plus, S's are smooth, but so are not R's. `;)`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107962/should-the-issues-tag-be-removed

Comment: @Esoteric: Dammit, you're right. My search skills are clearly lacking. :(  (Also, that was posted in 2011 -- _why is that tag still there???_)